# How to select item on spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

i use Retrofit,
item shown but i can't selected.
after clicking item,  toast and spinner not show anything (i can't select item on spinner).......

```
private List<String> spinnerItem;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        spinnerItem = new ArrayList<>();
        setSpinner();
    }

public void displayCities(List<CityResponse.City> cities) {
        mainBinding.helloText.setText(cities.get(508).getNama());
        for (CityResponse.City city : cities) {
            Log.d(TAG, city.getNama());
            spinnerItem.add(city.getNama());
        }
    }

private void setSpinner(){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItem);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mainBinding.spinnerCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        mainBinding.spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String citySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "City : " + citySelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(CityActivity.this, "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You dont have to Call notifyDataSetChanged. Selecting item does it already

Comment: i've try. but, i can't select item on spinner

Comment: hmmm change the color of your spinner to red or something different than white. Maybe your spinner text color and background color are white thats why you cant see anything after selection. And is the toast shown with empty value like `City: ` or not shown at all ?

Comment: i've change to red, not work
and Toast not shown at all

Comment: and where do you call `displayCities()`?

Comment: i call in CityPresenter.java

Comment: ok try to extract `adapter` as class variable, not the function `setSpinner()` variable. So you would have like: 

`private void setSpinner() {
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItem);`

and in `displayCities()` add `adapter.notiftDataSetChanged()` after `spinnerItem.add(city.getNama());`

Comment: wow.. thank you so much. it's work

Comment: ok I will post an answer explaining a bit

Comment: you can accept my answer aswell if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current solution:

You set the adapter in the `setSpinner()` with a list called `spinnerItem` which is empty for this moment. Then in `displayCities()` you fill list with values but forget to notify the adapter about new values added.

```java
public void displayCities(List<CityResponse.City> cities) {
        for (CityResponse.City city : cities) {
            spinnerItem.add(city.getNama());
        }
        // 2. notify adapter that you have inserted new cities to the list
}

private void setSpinner(){
        // 1. set the adapter with spinnerItem which is empty here
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(..., ..., spinnerItem);
        mainBinding.spinnerCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
}
```

If `adapter` is local variable for `setSpinner()` then `displayCities()` does not have access to the `adapter`. Create `adapter` as global and then you can call `adapter.notiftDataSetChanged()` in point 2 comment

Answer (score 0):

Your setSpinner() method:

```
private void setSpinner(final Context context, Spinner spinnerCity, List<Object> spinnerItem) {
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItem);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCity.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String citySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(context, "City : " + citySelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

CityActivity.java:

```
Spinner spinnerCity = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String[] spinnerItem = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
setSpinner(CityActivity.this, spinnerCity, Arrays.<Object>asList(spinnerItem));
```

Comment: not work, i've update post, help me to check
i use Retrofit, like [link](https://github.com/farizdotid/mahasiswa-app-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/meridianid/farizdotid/mahasiswaapp/activity/TambahMatkulActivity.java)